# Max-msp or Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing, max-msp-jitter

I want to program an interactive screen which will translate body movement into sound and not sure whether I should use Processing or Max-msp.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 8):

It very much depends on your setup.

You can do [2D frame differencing](http://cycling74.com/2009/10/26/making-connections-camera-data/) or [3D tracking with Kinect](http://cycling74.com/2010/12/02/using-microsoft-kinect-with-max/) and MSP is great for audio synthesis/processing. Since you patch the code live, it should be a lot faster to prototype than the regular Processing/Java cycle (write code,compile,test,debug,repeat).
If you're feeling comfortable with Max I would recommend it.

Otherwise, you can do the tracking with Processing, but I wouldn't recommend Processing for responsive audio applications. Depending on how much processing(video and audio) needs to be done, Java's Garbage Collector might kick in for a sweep of loitering objects when you least expect it and could cause delays and clicks in audio. Max is faster.

You could have a mix of the two, maybe using the [OSC protocol](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/) between Processing and Max, but it mostly depends on your setup and skills.

If you're more comfortable writing code than wiring objects, you could still use Java or Javascript in Max.

I would say the simpler, the better, and since the output of your project is sound, I would say Max is your best bet.

HTH

Comment: I would go for the mix mentioned above with OSC.

Answer (score 1):

You can go just with Max/MSP/Jitter and web camera. The basic way of translating image into the audio is the determine quantity of motion (QoM) and use it to control synthesis parameters. I would suggest you to start with this article: https://cycling74.com/2009/10/26/making-connections-camera-data/ — it has a basic info about it and ready-to-use patch to quickly start working.

Answer (score -1):

I used MAX/MSP for this because there are many open source stuff outthere.

I used Kinect with Synapse. The Synapse package also provide max patch that give you all the body information (coordinates) that you can directly use as mapping parameters.